# Grant types supported by the Rest API

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2, apexrest

I have created a Apex Class and exposed the data as a REST API like below.

```
global with sharing class ReteriveSFAccountData {
    
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        try{    
}
}
```

Also created the connected API which allows  the API to be accessed via external application and I also created the service account. Currently the client application access the REST API in salesforce by giving the below

[image]

I wanted to understand if Salesforce supports anyother grant_type like Client_Credentials other than `password`. If the Client_credentials is supported what are the header paramters that needs to be passed to get the Access token from Salesforce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce supports a wide variety of OAuth flows. The available flows are documented in [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm).

Typically, external integrations should be authorized using the [User Agent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5), [Web Server](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5), or [JWT](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) Flows depending on the specific use case.

Comment: Does it support `client_credentials`

Comment: [No, it does not](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252922/does-salesforce-support-the-client-credentials-grant-for-oauth). You must always authorize as a user, but you should not store the user's credentials.